# Transform json data to another json using java and apache camel

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

How can i convert a json object from one structure to another in apache camel using java?

I have tried using jsonpath but I'm not sure if i am going in the right direction or how it's going to look at in the end.

```
ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(json);
LinkedHashMap full = ctx.read("$");
String fulldata = full.toString()
                .replace("date_of_birth", "birth")
                .replace("name", "person_name")
                .replace("full_name", "fullname")
                .replace("last_name", "last")
                .replace("middle_name", "middle")
                .replace("first_name", "first")
```

This is how my json looks like now

```
 "person": {
    "country_of_residence": [
      "USA"
    ],
    "document_number": "1",
    "document_type": "passport",
    "full_name": {
      "last_name": "John",
      "middle_name": "Jack",
      "first_name": "Dan"
    }
    "document_expiration_date": "2020-12-03",
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
{
    "label": [
        "user"
    ],
    "property": {
        "person_name": "name",
        "fullname": {
            "last": "John",
            "middle": "Jack",
            "first": "Dan"
        }
    }
    "id": {
        "expiry_date": "2020-12-03",
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `apache-camel`, but I have a small about of knowledge about `Java/JSON`. I use `GSON`. I would create two POJOs that mirror the two different JSON objects. I would then use the `Person` POJO to construct the other POJO. `GSON` takes care of everything before, in between, and after.

Comment: Agree with Sedrick, that this isn't a Camel-specific question. I am familiar with using Jackson JSON to rename fields while being marshaled.

Comment: Typically I've been using two different POJOs and mapping between those in a processor and then using camel do a `.unmarshall().process().marshall()`-chain with them. It is rather high amount of code for simple things but allows for very easy changes later on.